# headers already sent even if using ob_start()

Tags: php, smarty

I have a central index.php which prints the basic html template like:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
</html>
<body>

{dynamic php here (might include $smarty->display()}

</body>
</html>
<?php ob_end_flush(); ?>
```

Whenever a specific site is needed i will include it in the center and execute there. When logging in as a user, after all the validation checks i need to redirect via `header()`. But i can't because some HTML was already printed out. Ok, no problem. I surrounded my index.php with `ob_start()` at the start and `ob_end_flush()`; at the end of it. I am still getting the headers already sent error even though i use `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`. Why? Note: I am using SMARTY templating enginge for some templates that will be displayed via `$smarty->display()` in the center.

Anyone here has an idea why this happens?

Thanks!

EDIT: Actual code:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
/**
 * Main index.php, root template
 */

?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML>

    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 0);
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);
    ini_set("error_log", "logs/ERROR_LOG.txt");
```

EDIT 2:

Have narrowed the problem down to 2 changes in nav.php, which contains the navigation of the site. The navigation is a bunch of:

```
if($user->hasPermissionFor("specialsite")) {
    ?>

    <li><a href="...">MyLink</a></li>

    <?php
}
```

I simply added (since the last commit and actual code):

```
$smarty->display("GENERAL_LANGUAGE_PICKER.tpl");
```

The `GENERAL_LANGUAGE_PICKER.tpl` is a simple HTML template, showing some language pngs to pick a language. Nothing special. If i use this code, the site will break on login/logout because of the `header()` problem. If i don't use this code, everything works fine. Why does this break when using `$smarty->display()` in combination with `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` if it shouldnt? I mean: I am using `$smarty->display()` A LOT in specific sites inside of the whole enclosing `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()` stuff and i won't break...

EDIT 3:
I just simply can't get it to work. This is again code simply copied out from the project:

```
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="tourstep-two">
    <?php
    // Generate nav for this file, here i call nav.php in which i have 2x 
    // $smarty->display() which will break the code
    include_once("php/intern/nav.php");
    ?>
</nav>

<header style="background: url(images/layout/banner.png) no-repeat" class="banner">
    <img class="img-responsive img-center"
         src="images/layout/logo.png"
         alt="Logo">
</header>

<section id="tourstep-six">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-12">

        <?php
        // Here i am in the main content area. When using this $smarty->display everything is FINE and it does work
        $smarty->display("templates/GENERAL_SUCCESS.tpl");
```

Ok so there are 2 parts where i want to call $smarty->display(). Inside nav.php which renders the navigation and once at the start of the main content area. When doing so in the main content area IT WORKS and i get no errors. Once i try this inside nav.php it just breaks and the HTML will not be written to the buffer, instead written out and breaks my header() calls. I have no idea why. If i replace the $smarty->display() calls inside nav.php with the HTML they are rendering, it works. With the calls however it won't be written to the buffer. What the hell is doing smarty here and why won't it let me write that inside of nav.php? Any help appreciated...

Comment: Please show your code where you start output buffering. Note that absolutely nothing must come before that, not even a blank line.

Comment: Have you tried calling `ob_start()` before `session_start()`? `session_start()` will cause a cookie header to be sent.

Comment: @Chris: Yes, i have. Doesn't change anything. I have however just narrowed the problem down to something specific about Smarty. Will update main post.

Comment: Okay thanks. It's possible Smarty does something weird with output buffering internally, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Chris: Added more info... I dont understand what smarty is doing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else having the same problem: No, i wasn't my fault, it was a smarty bug. Updating fixed it, here is the description: https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/issues/187